# How much slower will my computer be with Ubuntu (instead of Lubuntu)?

Tags: lubuntu

So I was given an old computer which I'm going to use as a second desktop next to my main computer for minor tasks like checking my e-mails, listening to music etc.
It know has Lubuntu, but I'd prefer to use Ubuntu because it's fully supported and has a more appealing environment. Currently, Lubuntu uses about 400mb of my RAM, but how much more RAM will Ubuntu use? Do you suggest sticking to Lubuntu if I want speed or Ubuntu will work, too? Also, if I format the Hard Disk, will ubuntu automatically find the drivers or I'm going to have to download them manually?

This is its hardware:
Intel Pentium 4 CPU 2.40GHz ‖ RAM 1508 MiB ‖ Gigabyte 8IG1000MK ‖ nVidia NV44A GeForce 6200

Comment: "Fully supported" by the people who gave you the PC? You can run Lubuntu and install whatever software you want from mainstream Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Lubuntu is also a supported variant of Ubuntu, versions 12.04 lts and 14.04 lts.  I don't know that the computer would be slower, but less responsive.  Ubuntu uses a lot of power running desktop graphics and animations - once a program is open (and the desktop is not active) I think there would be little difference.

Comment: Ubuntustudio is surprisingly fast and responsive on old, resource strapped computers, and you definitely don't sacrifice style. Plus there's a unity like launcher set to autohide at the bottom of the screen. Actually quicker than Lubuntu from my experience. https://ubuntustudio.org/download/

Comment: you're right, however, ubuuntu vanilla is supported for 5 years lts and all other versions are only supported for 3.

Comment: You system configuration meet with min system requirements of  ubuntu ... & you can format your disk it have essential drivers by default (makce backup of personal data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, difference in performance of Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu is hardly noticeable. If your computer cannot handle standard Ubuntu with Gnome, it will also perform poor with lightweight Ubuntu versions.